# gRPC Failure after upgrading to .net 8 p6

Tags: c#, browser, blazor, grpc, blazor-webassembly

After upgrading to .net 8 p6 our app fails on some devices showing this error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer (100)     
Unhandled Exception rendering component: Typeinitialization_Type,Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcFrotocolConstants System.TypeInitializationException: Typeinitialization_Type, grpc.net.client.internal.GrpcProtocolconstants system.FormatException: net_http_headers_invalid_value, application/grpc 

Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionstack 

at Microsoft.Extensions.Dependencyinjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor'2 

Microsoft.Extensions.Dependencyinjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolver Context, Microsoft.Extensions.Dependencyznjection, version=8.0.0.0, Culture-neutral, PublickeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.corelib, version:8.0.0.0" culture-neutral, PublickeyToken=adb9793829ddae60].VisitCaliSiteMain(ServiceCaliSite, RuntimeResolverContext) 

at Microsort.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeRe solver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCaliSite, RuntimeResolverContext) at Microsort.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor'2 ((Microsort.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolver Context, Microsort.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, system.Private.corelib, Version-8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
```

Any idea what the problem is? I can't understand what this even means.

Thanks a lot for the help!